# SQLite decimal(12,2) , how it actually works?

Tags: sqlite

I suppose that create table query with column decimal(12,2) means number with maximum 12 digits and 2 of that are decimal, right?
When I use update statement on this column, like

"update table set 'x' = 'x' + 0.01 where.....""

I always get a number with 12 digits behind decimal .
like, 0 = 0 + 0.01
result is 0.010000000001

which is not big problem for me but that 1 digit on the end is.
Should I change my create table statement cause obviously that 12 number doesn't work right thing for me,
thank you

Comment: Do you obtain that result in the CLI or through the C API? My guess is that you use the second one and `sqlite3_column_double`. Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: I am using c# to send update statement. My column in sqlite is decimal

Comment: Start by giving https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html a good read.

Comment: And [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

The method you use to retrieve the column clearly retrieves the column as `double`. Since there is no floating-point number corresponding to `0.01`, the value you obtain is rounded.

While retrieving the column be sure to use a class like [Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0), that performs operation on decimal numbers with the correct rounding and retrieve your column as:

`Round(dataReader.getDecimal(), 2);`